# how to access multiple json array?

Tags: android

please check my code it is corret way to access json array? the array "worldpopulation" data will be shown but array  "contacts" data willnot b shown  check my code m i correctly access?????????? my full code is here i just add new arrayin my json file"contacts" and acess it check my code please

```
               {
     "worldpopulation": [
     {
       "rank":1,
    "name": "Angelina",
       "url": "http://www.bounty4u.com/android/images/angie.jpg"
      },
       {   
       "rank":2,
     "name": "Ashton ",
       "url": "http://www.bounty4u.com/android/images/ashton.jpg"
    },
      {  
      "rank":3,
       "name": "Jackman",
      "url": "http://www.bounty4u.com/android/images/hugh.jpg"
        }

    ]
       ,

  "contacts": [
               {
    "id":1,
    "Item": "Calories",
     "Quantity": "150g"
  },
  {   
     "id":2,
     "Item": "Calcium",
       "Quantity": "250g"
    },
     {  
 "id":3,
 "Item": "Carbohydrates",
  "Quantity": "300g"
}

]
}








                                try {

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 
       15000);
                HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(DescriptionAPI);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                InputStream atomInputStream = 
     response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
 InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

                String line;
                String str = "";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                    str += line;
                }


                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
                    JSONArray data = 
          json.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");


                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i); 

                    //    JSONObject category = 
           object.getJSONObject("Category");


    Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(object.getString("rank")));
                        Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));
                        Category_image.add(object.getString("url"));

                        Log.d("Category name", Category_name.get(i));
                        listview.setAdapter(cla);




                    }
                   ////Acess Json array Contacts/////////////////////

                    JSONArray data2 = json.getJSONArray("contacts");
                final TableLayout table = (TableLayout)  
          findViewById(R.id.table2);
                for (int j = 0; j < data2.length(); j++)
                {
                    final View row = createRow(data2.getJSONObject(j));
                    table.addView(row);


                }   



            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //  IOConnect = 1;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   




    }


public View createRow(JSONObject item) throws JSONException {
        View row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rows, null);
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.localTime)).setText(item
                .getString("Item"));
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.apprentTemp)).setText(item
                .getString("Quantity"));

        return row;
    }
```

Comment: put it into a single json object and parse... you will get all those object arrays

Comment: how? edit my code please im confuse

Comment: cjheck my json file is correctly define? i make myself this json file for testing